# How to access Amazon EC2 files via web browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian, remote-access

So I have an Amazon EC2 Free Tier Instance with Debian Jessie. There's a software running that generates an html file I'd like to access remotely.

When connected to the instance via SSH, I can remotely open a web browser and go to 127.0.0.1:8083/index.html?PARAMETER1=...&PARAMETER2=...

Now doing this is very tedious because the browser is slow. I'd like to be able to access to this file directly using the web browser in my local machine.

How do I do this? I tried replacing 127.0.0.1 with the Public IPv4 but it won't work. Do I have to open the port?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to open port 8083 using the security groups inbound rules for the ec2 instance. Then use the public IP to access the file.